# Check the Desired Capacity of an AWS Autoscaling Group using Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, methods, boto3, autoscaling

Suppose I have made a simple connection to an AWS Autoscaling Group (ASG) using boto3 like this:

```
 import boto3

 region_name = "us-west-2"
 asg_session = boto3.session.Session()
 asg_client = asg_session.client(service_name="autoscaling", region_name=region_name)
```

Now, I want to check the desired capacity of that ASG using a boto3 method. I know I can set the capacity like this:

```
  response = asg_client.set_desired_capacity(
            AutoScalingGroupName='my-asg',
            DesiredCapacity=123,
            HonorCooldown=False
        )
```

Update: I tried running describe like this:

```
describe_response = asg_client.describe_auto_scaling_groups(
    AutoScalingGroupNames=[
        'my-asg',
    ]
)
print(describe_response)
```

However, the response didn't seem to have the desired capacity.

```
{'AutoScalingGroups': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '12345678-abcd', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 't3h3i3s7-e0x8a7m3p4l2e', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '335', 'date': 'Thu, 06 Oct 2022 15:20:31 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

How do I simply get the current desired capacity value in my python script?

Comment: [describe_auto_scaling_groups()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/autoscaling.html#AutoScaling.Client.describe_auto_scaling_groups).

Comment: What is the `NextToken` value suppose to be? Can I just leave that out?

Comment: You leave that out. That's for pagination if you hit max number of results. see also https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html

Comment: See my update to the question.

Comment: That response means that no autoscaling groups exist in that region with that name.

Comment: OK, I found the issue. It wasn't the region. I actually had the incorrect AuscalingGroup name plugged. in.